# I need to display an error if other than +, / and 0-9 is in the string

Tags: php, regex, codeigniter

My pattern matching expression is like this i want to check and return error message.

```
 public function checkthe($str)
        {
                if(preg_match('/^\(?[+]?[0-9]{3,4}[-. ]?[0-9]{8,10}$/', $str)==TRUE)
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {   
                    $this->form_validation->set_message('checkthe', 'The %s should be in     format XXX-XXXXXXXX');
                    return false;
                }   
        }
```

Comment: Your attempt doesn't match your title. Which one is correct?

Comment: i am expecting code for title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need display error if other than + / and 0-9 in the string

If that is indeed the case your regex code should be:

```
public function checkthe($str) {
    return preg_match('~^[+/0-9]+$~', $str);
}
```

Though it is always better to include your sample inputs.